# whether 2 arraylist is equal or not

Tags: arraylist, equality

```
public boolean isSymmetric(TreeNode A) {
        if(A==null)
            return true;
     /*   if(isSymmetric(A.left) && isSymmetric(A.right))
            return 1;
        else return 0;*/
        ArrayList<Integer> al1= preorder(A);
        System.out.println(al1);
        al.clear(); 
        //System.out.println("common "+al);
        p=invertTree(A);
        ArrayList<Integer> al2= preorder(p);
        System.out.println(al2);
        int i=0,j=0;
        while(i<al1.size() && i<al2.size())
        {
            System.out.println(al1.get(i)+" "+al2.get(i));
            if(al1.get(i)!=al2.get(i))
                    return false;
            i++;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

i am trying to compare whether 2 arraylist are having same elements in same sequence or not

Your input

> [1,2,2,null,3,null,3]

stdout

> [1, 2, -1, 3, -1, -1, 2, -1, 3, -1, -1] //printed al1
>
> [1, 2, 3, -1, -1, -1, 2, 3, -1, -1, -1] //printed al2
>
> 1 1 2 2 3 3
>
> -1 -1
>
> -1 -1
>
> -1 -1 2 2 3 3
>
> -1 -1
>
> -1 -1
>
> -1 -1

//don't know how they are showing same elements 
Output
true

Expected
false

Comment: You can sort both then use contains on both. It might be one solution

Comment: i am trying check if tree is symmetric...for that i took preorder of the tree then inverted it and again took preorder , now i am checking if both are same i,e, in terms of order then this tree is symmetric.........since it is the same tree that is why size will be same and i can't sort it as it will change the sequence which is required to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you have al1 and al2 ArrayLists. This is how you can check whether they are equal (same size and same values in all positions)

```
boolean same = true;
if ((al1 == null) != (al2 == null)) {
    same = false;
} 
if (al1.size() != al2.size()) {
    same = false;
} else {
    for (int i = 0; same && (same = al1.get(i).equals(al2.get(i)); i++);
    //The result is in same
}
```

Comment: did this...                                                                                                            
    boolean same=true;
    for ( i = 0; (i<al1.size())&&same && (same = al1.get(i).equals(al2.get(i))); i++);
        return same;                                                                                                                                                     
 still giving false!

Comment: @gotu according to your question you intended the output to be false, but it was true. In this comment of yours you say that the output was true and you expected it to be false. We need to clarify this. Is 1, 2 the same as 2, 1? Is 1, 2, 3 the same as 1, 2? I try to find out what you expect, as it seems that your comment here contradicts to the expectation defined in the question. I assumed that you want to determine whether all elements on all positions are the same, so 1, 2 would not equal to 2, 1.

Comment: my al1 and al2 is printing correctly but when i am trying to compare them, they are showing same element at same index...why it is doing this and how to resolve it

Comment: @gotu gow is your preorder method look like?